# Can't destroy CKEditor instances

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to refresh all my CKEditor instances using this code:

```
        for(name in CKEDITOR.instances)
        {
            console.log(name);
            CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy();
            //Also tried this
            //CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy(true);

        }
        CKEDITOR.inlineAll();
```

and I'm receiving this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getRanges' of null.
```

The interesting part is that, if I use the code directly in the console, it works just fine.

Anyone has any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: I would recommend investigating the error further using a JS debugger, both chrome dev tools and firebug support break on error. You should examine the call stack and figure out why the null is there.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I'll have to workaround if I decide to keep it with CKEditor...

Comment: I'm on CKE 4.5.3 and am still seeing this error. Has anyone found any way to at least not log it out as an error?

Comment: I'm on CKE 4.6.2 and am still seeing this error. Has anyone found any way to at least not log it out as an error?

Answer (score 0):

Check this bug report: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10219

In 4.1 and 4.0.3 we have partially fixed this issue, but... only partially :). However, this error shouldn't cause any problems - it is completely harmless.

Comment: It's not completely harmless. In my case, I have several editors in one page and only the first one works.
I'll try 4.1 to see what happens.

Comment: I tried 4.1 and, instead of solving the issue, now I have more issues... =(

Comment: I presume that you have issues completely elsewhere. I investigated this ticket and that error is thrown in native event callback in `setTimeout` therefore it cannot block other code. Regarding 4.1 - it introduces completely new Advanced Content Filter which requires some work to configure it in some cases - read http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.1-Released

Comment: You're probably right about this new issues. They must me due to this ACF thing. But the issue with the destroy method is still unfixed in 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue but it seems to be fixed in ck-editor-dev repositories.
Somebody checked in a fix 2 days ago for CKEDITOR 4.1.1 milestone.
Check http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10219 again to access the change link in git.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. You can try adding a timeout (100 ms or more) before executing CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy();

Example:

```html
setTimeout(function(){
  CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy();               
},100);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).